# ajax form handling an array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

am trying to handle an array comes from php file after submitting the form data , the value of data after submitting the form is = ARRAY but i cant use this array in any way , any idea how can i handle this array !!!!

Javascript :

```
   $('#file').live('change',function(){
       $('#preview').html('');
       $('#preview').html('<img src="loader.gif" />');
       $('#data').ajaxForm(function(data){
               $(data['toshow']).insertBefore('.pic_content').hide().fadeIn(1000);

       }).submit();

  });
```

PHP :

```
....
....etc
echo json_encode(array('toshow'=>somedata,'data'=>somedata));
```

JSON String come from server

```
{"toshow":"\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t<table class=\"out\">\r\n\t\t\t<tr ><td class=\"img\"><a title=\"2012-06-02 01-22-09\" rel=\"prettyPhoto\" href=\"img\/2012-06-02 01-22-09.284.jpg\"><img  src=\"img\/thumb\/2012-06-02 01-22-09.284.jpg\"\/><\/a><\/td><\/tr>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<table cellSpacing=\"1\" cellPadding=\"0\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr><td class=\"data\"><span class=\"click\">2012-06-02 01-22-09<\/span><\/td><\/tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr><td class=\"data\"><span class=\"click\">Download<\/span><\/td><\/tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr><td class=\"data\"><a href=\"img\/2012-06-02 01-22-09.284.jpg\"><span class=\"click\">View<\/span><\/a><\/td><\/tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/table>\r\n\t\t\t<\/td>\r\n\t\t\t<\/tr>\r\n\t\t<\/table>","span":"<span class='text'><img src='greencheck.png'\/>2012-06-02 01-22-09 Uploaded ,File Size =152Kb <\/span>"}
```

Comment: so what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Your first `.html` call is redundant, and you have a syntax error in `ajaxForm` because it has a `});` too many.

Answer (score 3):

better to convert array to json format using  **json_encode($array)**. json data can easily  be handled by Javascript

Comment: +1, and adding some explanation (may be with an example) would make this a good answer :)

Comment: i have tried convert array to an json format and send the array , problem is am still getting data as an one value ONT as ex.. data[0], data[1] ...   echo json_encode(array('toshow'=>$send,'span'=>"<span class='text'>"))  .... so the coming data in javascript file is like one variable !!

Comment: @dmk002 , the coming data from php come as one variable !!! i mean am send the data as array json_encode($array) but in javascript its come as one variable so when am use data.toshow = undefined

Comment: try eval("(" + data + ')'); before you process data

Answer (score 1):

You can't echo array directly, it will output `Array`  only.

You need to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Comment: yes that's right , still problem i dont know how handle the coming json data in my javascript  function

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the array via PHP also with jQuery

for jQuery use - jQuery each

for PHP use - foreach or for loop

or try

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP side you have to insert `json_encode($array)` AND in the JS side instead of using `data['toshow']` use `data.toshow`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have tried this way , still cant use data.toshow always = undefined , i cant just use variable data as it is only

Comment: Can you echo `json_encode($array)` and send us the output? Or, maybe you forgot to actually `echo` the function on the PHP side. Remember that in PHP you have to write `echo json_encode($array)`

Answer (score 0):

Send out a JSON response, like this from PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($yourarray);
?>
```

Then to adapt your AJAX function, do this:

```
  $('#file').live('change',function(){
       $('#preview').html('');
       $('#preview').html('<img src="loader.gif" />');
       $('#data').ajaxForm(function(data){
               var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               //acess it like
               alert(jsonData.toshow); //alert for your testing
               $(jsonData.toshow).insertBefore('.pic_content').hide().fadeIn(1000);

       }).submit();

  });
```

- EDIT *
  Changes, update according the plug-in docs.

Having never used the .ajaxForm jQuery plug-in, I went after the documentation, I'm going to put the code here, as clear as possible from what I read, I'm even letting the plug-in parse the response automatically into json.

I didn't see any .ajaxForm().submit(), and there's no need to it according to the docs.

```
$('#file').live('change',function(){
    $('#preview').html('');
    $('#preview').html('<img src="loader.gif" />');
        $('#data').ajaxForm({ 
            dataType:  'json',
            success:   function(data){
                alert("json string response from php: "+ data.toshow);
                $(data.toshow).insertBefore('.pic_content').hide().fadeIn(1000);    
            }
        }); 
});
```

dataType makes the plugin parse the response to json alone.
and the success: function(data) happens if there was a response from PHP only.
Implement it carefully, and give link if you still didn't get it right.

Comment: I edited before your answer mate, it's jsonData.toshow, the variable that uses jQuery to parse the response into json.

Comment: Then your data is not a json response from PHP, you should look into that, the parse itself is quite simple and is 100% correct.

Comment: i have edit my post and added the value of data come from php file Please have a look and give me your advice , still cant do as you said jsonData.toshow , jsonData.data ... etc

Comment: just updated my code entirely, check the bottom part, checked the documentation of the plug-in you are using.

Comment: thanks Andre , problem is with coming data from php have many {/,<a>...etc} sample , i have tried send only an text working perfectly but in case sending such as <a href="www.google.com"></a> problem start and i cant read the data as json data !!!

Comment: I'm sorry to tel you @moata_u, but JSON Encode is perfectly capable of handling any HTML. I don't see no reason, why it shouldn't be working. If it's working with regular text, but why don't you share the JSON String that really comes from the server, if you need a more in-depth help.